Flutter camera - preview rotated
For some reason (only on some of the phones) my camera preview is rotated 90 degrees.
Device orientation utils on debug says the same thing for working and not working phones: D/CameraOrientationUtil(14552): getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=90
Using camera: ^0.11.0+1
This is how I build a preview: Expanded(child: _cameraController!.buildPreview()),
Which results in:

when I take a pic tho, the rotation is fine:

I can rotate the view, but then "working" phones are rotated... If anybody has any ideas I'd really appreciate it.

I had the same issue: just downgrade camera to version ^0.10.6

This one saved my week! 10x!

try this
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Future<img.Image?> fixImageRotation(String imagePath) async {
  try {
    final bytes = await File(imagePath).readAsBytes();
    final image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
    if (image == null) return null;

    final exifData = await readExifFromBytes(bytes);
    final orientation = exifData['Orientation']?.printable ?? '1';

    int rotationDegrees;
    switch (orientation) {
      case '3':
        rotationDegrees = 180;
        break;
      case '6':
        rotationDegrees = 90;
        break;
      case '8':
        rotationDegrees = 270;
        break;
      default:
        rotationDegrees = 0;
    }

    if (rotationDegrees != 0) {
      return img.copyRotate(image, rotationDegrees);
    }
    return image;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}

Future<Map<String, IfdTag>> readExifFromBytes(Uint8List bytes) async {
  final byteData = ByteData.sublistView(bytes);
  final exifData = await readExifFromByteData(byteData);
  return exifData;
}

